# multiple connected pie charts in ms excel

Tags: excel

I have a data set in which two categories (x,y) are there and category y has another sub categories (a,b) and then category b has super sub categories (c,d). Now I want to plot a pie chart which can reflect my data as below :
the first pie chart should reflect categories x and y
second pie chart (which is connected to first like pie of pie) and reflects category a and b
third pie chart again should reflect category c and d. and this one is again connected to second chart.

Can anyone suggest if it is possible in Excel? if yes how to arrange data and plot the charts.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you simply create three pie charts? You could base them on three pivots (with each showing either x/y a/b c/d) with shared slicers if you wanted them all to respond to filters (to make a slicer affect multiple pivots right click it, go to Report Connections and select the pivots you want to connect to the slicer).